# ¿Se puede acceder a un elemento hijo de un objeto JSON mediante una variable?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Tengo un formulario que con un combobox que al seleccionar una opción la voy a modificar, por lo que creo una copia del objeto seleccionado en otra variable, las modificaciones que hago, las hago a la copia y luego actualizo el elemento en cuestión. Pero, quería hacer esto desde una función, en la que al editar uno de los inputs con nombre o Id "nombreProducto" yo ir a buscar al objeto del json el elemento nombreProducto y asignarle el valor que corresponda y así sucesivamente para los demás elementos, la manera en la que lo intento es:

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productos: [
        { id: "1", nombreProducto: "Tennis", costoProducto: 0, estado: false },
        { id: "2", nombreProducto: "Camisa", costoProducto: 0, estado: false },
        { id: "3", nombreProducto: "Fajas", costoProducto: 0, estado: false }
      ],
      producto: { id: "", nombreProducto: "", costoProducto: 0, estado: false }
    };

    this.handleDropdown = this.handleDropdown.bind(this);
    this.handleDropDownState = this.handleDropDownState.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleDropdown(event) {
    const objetoSeleccionado = event.target.value;

    if (!(objetoSeleccionado === null || objetoSeleccionado === undefined)) {
      const objeto = this.state[event.target.name].find(
        objeto => objeto.id === objetoSeleccionado
      );
      this.setState(
        {
          producto: objeto
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.producto);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const nombreElemento = event.target.name;

    if (!(nombreElemento === null || nombreElemento === undefined)) {
      this.setState(
        { [this.state.producto[nombreElemento]]: event.target.value },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.producto);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  handleDropDownState(event) {
    if (!(event.target.name === null || event.target.name === undefined)) {
      let producto = this.state.producto;
      producto.estado = event.target.checked;
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: producto });

      this.setState({
        [this.state.productos.map(
          productoFinal => productoFinal.id === producto.id
        )]: [producto]
      });
      console.log(this.state);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select name="productos" onChange={e => this.handleDropdown(e)}>
          {this.state.productos.map((p, i) => {
            return (
              <option key={i} value={p.id}>
                {p.nombreProducto}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="nombreProducto">
          Nombre del Producto:{" "}
          <input
            id="nombreProducto"
            name="nombreProducto"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Pero esto me no me actualiza el state, es más haciendo debug, veo que cuando hago esto: `[this.state.producto[nombreElemento]]` retorna undefined, asumo que lo estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Más que guardar el producto completo, lo que en realidad necesitas es guardar el `id` de tu producto, que te dará una referencia para saber el producto exacto a modificar más tarde.
Hice algunas modificaciones a tu snippet para cambiar el nombre del producto (que al menos eso entendí que es lo que querías hacer) que eventualmente podrías extenderlo a los demás atributos del producto. Atento a los comentarios más adelante, que es donde principalmente hice los cambios de tu código.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productos: [
        { id: '1', nombreProducto: 'Tennis', costoProducto: 0, estado: false },
        { id: '2', nombreProducto: 'Camisa', costoProducto: 0, estado: false },
        { id: '3', nombreProducto: 'Fajas', costoProducto: 0, estado: false }
      ],
      // Le puse 1 por defecto, pero ahí verás tu si quieres que sea null o algo
      // más
      productoId: "1"
    };

    this.handleDropdown = this.handleDropdown.bind(this);
    this.handleDropDownState = this.handleDropDownState.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleDropdown(event) {
    const objetoSeleccionado = event.target.value;

    if (!(objetoSeleccionado === null || objetoSeleccionado === undefined)) {
      const objeto = this.state.productos.find(
        (objeto) => objeto.id === objetoSeleccionado
      );
      // Seteo de id al cambiar el select
      this.setState({ productoId: objeto.id });
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const { productoId, productos } = this.state;

    if (!(name === null || name === undefined) && productoId !== null) {
      // Acá realiza un spreading del arreglo de productos para copiarlo, donde
      // se modificará el producto basado en su id y luego se cambiará el state
      // actual por el nuevo
      let productoCopy = [...productos];
      const idx = productoCopy.findIndex((p) => p.id == productoId);
      productoCopy[idx] = { ...productoCopy[idx], [name]: value };
      this.setState({ productos: productoCopy });
    }
  }

  handleDropDownState(event) {
    if (!(event.target.name === null || event.target.name === undefined)) {
      let producto = this.state.producto;
      producto.estado = event.target.checked;
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: producto });

      this.setState({
        [this.state.productos.map(
          (productoFinal) => productoFinal.id === producto.id
        )]: [producto]
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select name="productos" onChange={(e) => this.handleDropdown(e)}>
          {this.state.productos.map((p, i) => {
            return (
              <option key={i} value={p.id}>
                {p.nombreProducto}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="nombreProducto">
          Nombre del Producto:{' '}
          <input
            id="nombreProducto"
            name="nombreProducto"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La mejor forma de actualizar el estado es hacerlo de forma **inmutable** y en lo que te estabas equivocando era que no ponías en el setState la variable "producto" que es la variable de estado que vas a modificar (aunque tu solo quieras modificar uno de los elementos del objecto producto, en el setState hay que indicar la variable a modificar aunque tu solo quieras modificar un elemento de un objeto o de una lista).

```
  handleInputChange(event) {
    const nombreElemento = event.target.name;

    if (!(nombreElemento === null || nombreElemento === undefined)) {
      this.setState({
        producto: {
          ...this.state.producto,
          [this.state.producto[nombreElemento]]: event.target.value
        }
      })
    }
  }
```